# Deleting parent element using Linq to XML

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have an XML File of this sort

```
<BallList>
<Brand name="xyz">
    <BallName>ball A</BallName>
    <DateApproved>Jan-12</DateApproved>
    <link>www.a.com</link>
</Brand>
<Brand name="abc">
    <BallName>Ball B</BallName>
    <DateApproved>Jan-02</DateApproved>
    <link>www.b.com</link>
</Brand>
</BallList>
```

In This way there are around 150 brands and 8000 ball names. I know this is not a good way to represent the XML, but now as the data is huge, structure cannot be modified.

I need to delete "Brand" node by comparing it with its ballname

Here is the code that I am trying out:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("NetBalls.xml"));
doc.Elements("Brand")
   .Where(s => s.Attribute("name").Value == DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
   .Elements("BallName")
   .Where(l => l.Value == textbox1.Text)
   .AncestorsAndSelf()
   .Remove();
```

I am trying to search for brand and go into its element node and check its node and delete its parent.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of navigating down to the child nodes and back up again, just embed the child-level criteria in a `Where` query against the elements you actually want:

```
doc.Elements("Brand")
   .Where(s => s.Attribute("name").Value == selectedBrand)
   .Where(s => s.Elements("BallName").Any(l => l.Value == selectedValue))
   .Remove();
```

This way, your Linq query more closely matches your English query: "Find me all of the Brand elements where the name attribute is x, and their Ballname element is y, and remove it."

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove the brand element? Try this:

```
xml.Elements("Brand")
   .Where(s => s.Attribute("name").Value == DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
   .Elements("BallName")
   .Where(l => l.Value == textbox1.Text)
   .Select(x => x.Parent)
   .Remove();
```

This will remove all Brand elements where the conditions apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the selection criteria in a single where clause:

```
doc.Elements("Brand")
    .Where(brand =>
        (string)brand.Attribute("name") == DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text &&
        brand.Elements("BallName").Any(ballName => (string)ballName == textbox1.Text))
    .Remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 string brandName = "xyz";
 string ballName = "ball A";
 var brands = doc.Elements("Brand").Where(s => s.Attribute("name").Value == brandName);
 foreach (var brand in brands)
 {
     if(brand.Elements("BallName").Any(l => l.Value == ballName))
     {
         brand.Remove();
     }
 }
```